# Find user profile page link from database

Tags: users, database

I know the link structure of a user page .
Like
For admin,it is example.com/users/admin
But I want to know from database how can I find the link? or which table contains the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path "/users/admin" is actually an "alias" for something like "user/1", where 1 is the user id. In Drupal 7, these aliases are stored in the {url_alias} table along with the real path that they point to.

So if you want to figure out what user the alias "users/admin" points to, look in the {url_alias} table and you will see a column called "source", which should have something like "user/1". "1" in this example is the user id.